# Operator To Return if one and ONLY One Argument is True

Tags: c#, operators

I'm making an if statement in C# that I would like to return true if ONLY one of the parameters is true. I'll use `||` in the example because that's the closest thing I can think of:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

if(a == 1 || b == 2)
{
Console.Log("The first statement is true")
}

if(a == 1 || b == 3)
{
Console.Log("The second statement is true")
}

if(a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 3)
{
Console.Log("The third statement is true")
}

if(a == 1 || b == 0 || c == 3)
{
Console.Log("The fourth statement is true")
}

//Output:
//The second statement is true
//The third statement is true
```

Again, think of the `||` as the operator I'm looking for. Does such an operator exist, or should I define my own boolean function?

Comment: Note that you want `==` rather than `=` for all those comparisons. It's helpful to make your pseudo-code as realistic as possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet I completely forgot about that. I'm used to a big red line under my code telling me it's wrong...lol. Will fix now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For two expressions, you can just use XOR:

```
if (a == 1 ^ b == 0)
```

For more than two, you could do something like:

```
if (new[] { a == 1, b == 0, c == 2 }.Count(x => x) == 1)
```

That basically counts all the "true" elements of the array constructed from the expressions, and checks that the count is 1.

Admittedly that evaluate all the conditions first, and will count all of them even if the first two are true (so the final one is irrelevant). If that ends up being expensive for you, there are more complex alternatives, but I'd definitely stick to something like this unless it's actually a problem.

Comment: I was thinking `x ^ y ^ z` would work, but if all three are `true`, it incorrectly returns `true`. This seems to be the correct solution.

Comment: This seems to make sense. I'll implement this and get back to you here if I have any other issues. It really surprises me that such an operator like i described in the OP doesn't exist.

Comment: @TannerFix-ItSmith: Why does it surprise you? I can't remember *every* wanting something like this... and it would be odd in terms of being an operator with a variable number of arguments.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried this and it threw an error. Apparently bool[] doesn't have a .Count() method?

Comment: @TannerFix-ItSmith: You need a `using` directive for `System.Linq`, i.e. `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I'd assume that in an if statement like the one in my example: `if(a == 1 ^ b == 0 ^ c == 3)` it would do the following

1) evaluate `a == 1` to `true`.

2) replace `a == 1` with `true`, so that the line would be read as `if(true ^ b == 0 ^ c == 3)`

3) evaluate `b == 0` to `false`.

4) replace `b == 0` in the code with `false` so that the line would be read as `if(true ^ false ^ c == 3)`

5) evaluate `true ^ false` to `true`.

...And then, as I was typing this, I realized where this was going. Nevermind, lol.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such operator. However you can try this :

```
var statements = new[] { a == 0, b == 2, c == 2 };
switch (statements.Count(x => x))
{
    case 0: Console.WriteLine("None of statement is true"); break;
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("The {0} statement is true", 
            new[] { "first", "second", "third" }.Skip(statements.TakeWhile(x => !x).Count()).First());
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("More than one statement is true");
        break;
}
```

Output :

> The second statement is true

Comment: That doesn't check for only one of the expressions being true though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fixed it.

Comment: I don't *think* the OP needs to know which condition is true, although I could be wrong... (Note how in the example, the conditions are different in each `if` statement.)

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean by "I don't think"? I'm programming a game in Unity and I need to check if one and only one of three buttons is being pressed in the current frame using `bool Input.GetButton(string name)`.

Comment: That is exactly what he is saying. You only need to know one of them is true, but which one is true is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, okay. I overlooked the 'which' in his comment.

Comment: @TannerFix-ItSmith BTW since you are using that, you can chain the validation nicely with`new [] { "buttonX", "buttonY", "buttonZ" }.Count(Input.GetButton) == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 operands, the XOR (`^`) operator will do this. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> For **bool** operands, `^` computes the logical exclusive-or of its
>   operands; that is, the result is **true** if and only if exactly one of
>   its operands is **true**.

For three or more operators, [Jon is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757860/1715579), you will simply need to loop through the conditions. However, if there are *very many* conditions to check (or just a few very expensive conditions), you could possibly achieve a performance improvement by short-circuiting the result when the second `true` is found, like so:

```
var conditions = ...
if (conditions.Where(x => x).Take(2).Count() == 1)
```

Or if you'd prefer something less cryptic, perhaps an extension method

```
public static bool ExactlyOne(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var found = false;
    foreach(var x in source)
    {
        var result = predicate(x);
        if (result && found) {
            return false;
        }
        found = result;
    }

    return found;
}

var conditions = ...
if (conditions.ExactlyOne(x => x))
```

Comment: But, for multiple conditions, this would not give the results the OP wants. For instance `true ^ true ^ false ^ true` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to raise the same question. Would i need to enclose each pairing of operands within parenthesis like so: `if ((a == x ^ b == y) ^ c == z)` or would it be okay to write them without the parenthesis?

Comment: @JonSkeet Corrected and added a 'short-circuiting' solution so my answer is not completely extraneous next to yours :P